# How to export a value with newline character in excel format using php?

Tags: php, excel, newline

I am using PHPExcel to export data from my database to an excel file. So far it works perfectly. My problem is that I have a string value that I want to be separated in newline but must be contained in 1 cell.
How can I do this? I have successfully exported it but the data in that cell is only occupying a single line.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

```
foreach ($documents as $document){
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$row,$document->getSubject());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,$row,$document->getDescription());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2,$row,$document->getFrom());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3,$row,$document->getDateReceived());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4,$row,$document->getDueRD());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5,$row,$document->getDueDate());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6,$row,$document->getDue15Days());
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7,$row,$document->getChat());
    $row++;
}
```

The last row $document->getChat() is a string containing newline character "\n".

Example: "Name: message \n Name2: message \n Name: message"
will become:

"Name: message"

"Name2: message"

"Name: message"

in one excel column.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(7,$row,trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $document->getChat()));
```